# How to join docs in Solr?

Tags: solr

I have collection with data like:

```
"docs":[
 {"EventDate":"2019-01-29T00:03Z",
 "type":"Request",
 "RqID":"00000000000000000000000000000001"},
 {"EventDate":"2019-01-29T00:04Z",
 "type":"Response",
 "RqID":"00000000000000000000000000000001"},
 {"EventDate":"2019-01-29T01:45Z",
 "type":"Request",
 "RqID":"00000000000000000000000000000002"},
 {"EventDate":"2019-01-29T01:45Z",
 "type":"Response",
 "RqID":"00000000000000000000000000000002"},
]
```

I want to calculate "Response-Request" time. At SQL I did this by:

```
select rq, t2.EventType-t1.EventType from table t1, table t2
where t1.RqID = t2.RqID
and t1.type = 'Request'
and t2.type = 'Response'
```

Join in solr return me not joined docs. How can I do it in Solr?

Comment: You might want to take a look at  Math expressions in the Solr Streaming API https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_5/math-expressions.html

Comment: Thank you very much! Really good article. It's help in other case. But I don't understand how can I compare two sets of data in that case.

Answer (score 1):

If you would firstly [group the data](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_6/result-grouping.html#grouping-results-by-field) by rqID, and then using the [scalar math sub function](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_5/scalar-math.html#more-scalar-math-functions) with EventDate from the Response - EventDate from the Request, you should get the result you're looking for.

Comment: I don’t not understand how to use scalar math after grouping. Can you write an example?

Answer (score 0):

I can make a join:
q=type:"Request"&fl=*,resp[subquery]&resp.q={!term f=RqID v=$row.RqUID}&resp.fq= Response

But I have no idea how to calc duration.